# Reference object when destructuring

Tags: javascript

I'm playing with destructuring:

```
function create(){
 let obj={a:1,b:2}
obj.self=obj
 return obj
}
const {a,self} = create()
```

Is there a way to get the self object without adding such a property ?

```
function create(){
 let obj={a:1,b:2}
// removes   obj.self=obj
 return obj
}
const {a,this} = create()
```

In one line of code if possible!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap your `create` return value inside a temporary outer object, and then access the original object by property name from the outer object. This still allows you to pull out properties from the original object as well.

```
const {me:{a}, me} = {me:create()}
```

This will create the variable `a` using the property `a` from the object, and create the variable `me` which holds the entire object.

Or, to name it something other than the property name from the outer object (e.g., `foo` instead of `me`):

```
const {me:{a}, me:foo} = {me:create()}
```

This still requires making an additional property, but the property exists on the instantly-disposed wrapper object. This can be done entirely external to `create` so you don't need to touch the process of how the `create` function operates just to make it destructuring-friendly.